# Show NavigationDrawer below topBar but above bottomBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show NavigationDrawer below topBar but above bottomBar.

Here is what I have implemented so far. Currently, it is showing below topBar also below bottomBar.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            MyTopAppBar {
                scope.launch {
                    drawerState.open()
                }

            }
        },
        bottomBar = {


            MyBottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier.height(65.dp)) {
                val modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight();

                BottomAppBarItem(
                    "Calls",
                    Icons.Filled.Call,
                    false,
                    modifier
                )
                BottomAppBarItem(
                    "Search",
                    Icons.Filled.Search,
                    true,
                    modifier
                )
                BottomAppBarItem(
                    "Contacts",
                    Icons.Filled.AccountBox,
                    false,
                    modifier
                )

            }
        }


    ) { paddingValues ->



        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {

            ModalNavigationDrawer(gesturesEnabled = true, drawerContent = {

                DrawerContent()

            }, drawerState = drawerState) {


            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried testing with `zIndex` values within the Modifiers for each composable involved? look for how zIndex works in Compose and I think you will be able to make it work :)

Comment: You have move the ```BottomBar``` to screen content rather in ```Scaffold```. this way it will also cover the ```BottomBar```

Comment: @ChiragThummar then I have to manage BottomBar myself like giving it weight and keeping it at the bottom always. I think there would be some other way also.

Comment: As per my experience this is the way you can achieve it. because its not hard to mange it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to show the drawer above the Bottom Navigation

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
  val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

  Column {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                if (drawerState.isClosed) {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.open()
                    }
                } else {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.close()
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.List, contentDescription =null)
            }
        },
    )
    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            // Drawer Items 
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.Blue),
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Settings",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
                )
            }
        },
        content = {
            Scaffold(
                bottomBar = {
                    NavigationBar {
                        // Bottom navigation items
                        NavigationBarItem(
                            selected = false,
                            icon = {
                                Icon(
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                    contentDescription = null
                                )
                            },
                            onClick = {},
                        )
                    }
                },
                content = { paddingValues ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues))
                }
            )
        },
    )
 }
 }
```

Comment: kindly check this question also. if you can answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400575/open-navigationdrawer-from-left-edge-swipe-only-in-jetpack-compose