# Open NavigationDrawer from left edge swipe only in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have added NavigationDrawer in my app. Currently, if you swipe on the screen anywehere from left to right it opens the drawer. I don't want this behavior. I want it to open only I swipe from the left screen edge.

That's what is happening currently.

[image]

My code:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    ModalNavigationDrawer(gesturesEnabled = true,  drawerContent = {

        DrawerContent()

    }, drawerState = drawerState) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                MyTopAppBar {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.open()
                    }

                }
            },
            bottomBar = {
                MyBottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier.height(65.dp)) {
                    val modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxHeight();

                    BottomAppBarItem(
                        "Calls",
                        Icons.Filled.Call,
                        false,
                        modifier
                    )
                    BottomAppBarItem(
                        "Search",
                        Icons.Filled.Search,
                        true,
                        modifier
                    )
                    BottomAppBarItem(
                        "Contacts",
                        Icons.Filled.AccountBox,
                        false,
                        modifier
                    )

                }

            }
        ) { paddingValues ->

            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(paddingValues),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consume the `change` event when dragging `content` of ModalNavigationDrawer. Try wrapping your content with `Box` and setting [pointerInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInput(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)):

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = { LeftSide() }) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume() //<-- Intercept event
                }
            }) { Content() }

}
```